# Why doesn't it use all of the processor?

Tags: java

I wrote a java program to test the capabilities of processors by running an amount of calculations and then matching it up against my friends computers.

However when I run the program, it doesn't use 100% of the processor. The processing power goes from 1-2% to 27% and the RAM stays at 34%.

Is this just the way java or processors work? or is it something with my code? Here's the class that handles the calculation(Note: I'm still learning how to program, and I'm interested in the way the software interacts with the hardware):

```
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class Main {

    static int numberToCalculate = 100;
    static int otherNumberToCalculate = 50;
    static String typeOfCalculation = "all";
    static int calculated;
    static int calculations = 10000000;

    public static void calculate(JTextPane j, JTextPane j2) {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i <= calculations; i++) {

            switch(typeOfCalculation) {
            case "Divide":
                calculated = numberToCalculate / otherNumberToCalculate;
                break;

            case "Multiply":
                calculated = numberToCalculate * otherNumberToCalculate;
                break;

            case "Plus":
                calculated = numberToCalculate + otherNumberToCalculate;
                break;

            case "Minus":
                calculated = numberToCalculate - otherNumberToCalculate;
                break;

            case "All":
                calculated = numberToCalculate / otherNumberToCalculate;
                calculated = calculated * otherNumberToCalculate;
                calculated = calculated + otherNumberToCalculate;
                calculated = calculated - otherNumberToCalculate;
                break;

            default:
                Test.UpdateText(j, "Error, please pick type of calculation.");
                Test.UpdateText(j2, "Error, please pick type of calculation.");
                break;
            }
            if(i == calculations) {
                Test.UpdateText(j, "Milliseconds: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
                Test.UpdateText(j2, "Result: " + calculated);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Test.window();
    }

}
```

And here's a picture of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH1VA.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're on a multi-processor machine, you're only going to be maxing out one processor with this code. I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you have 4 processors (or 2 with hyperthreading). That would explain why you're only getting 27% utilization.

You'll need to spin up extra threads doing calculations as well if you want to truly max out all of the cores in your system.

Comment: Ahh, that makes perfect sense, I have a quad core processor, and my code only uses a single thread *facepalm*. Thanks for your quick answer :) I will now attempt to rewrite it to use as many cores as the processor has.

Answer (score 2):

The answer has already been given: your code uses a single thread and can't use all the capacity of your system. You can try the program below for a quick test - it first runs with a single thread as well, then it uses all the processors (you might need to increase the size (100,000,000) of the loop depending on your machine to have enough time to see the difference):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
                sum += Math.log(i);
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    };

    r.run(); //first run: single thread

    //second run: as many threads as processors
    for (int i = 0; i < Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); i++) {
        executor.submit(r);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see. I hope you wouldn't mind that I use some of your code to improve my program? Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @Remi Of course not - feel free to use it. One additional note: if you use Swing then you will need to make sure all the GUI related stuff is called from the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT = GUI thread). If not you will see some weird behaviour.